# Cygwin - running a script on startup

Tags: cygwin

I have a small script, myscript.sh, that I want to run every time I start Cygwin - right now it just echoes "hello" but I want it to have useful functionality later.

Another post said to modify my .bash_profile file which I did, appending "source myscript.sh", but it didn't do anything.

Is there a way to do this? Running latest Cygwin from Win7.

Comment: You could try appending that line to `.bashrc`, because it is possible that `.bash_profile` isn't actually being run.

Answer (score 0):

I put things like this in my `.bashrc` file.

It's more common to execute scripts like this (rather than using the `source` command):

```
/path/to/script/script.sh
```

More specifically it might look like this:

```
/home/jahroy/bin/init-script.sh
```

The file has to be executable and should begin with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You can substitute `bash` with your shell of choice.